# Does app server instance require restart, if we update DB

Tags: database, spring-mvc

DB content/rows are updated. Does any appserver need a restart to reflect the rows in appserver instances.

Answer (score 0):

From my experience, the answer is - it depends.
If you have 2 servers (cloned) and 2 DBs (cloned) and a gateway to somehow maintain exactly the same data without any discrepancies in both the DBs (refer to this https://docs.oracle.com/goldengate/c1230/gg-winux/GGCON/introduction-oracle-goldengate.htm#GGCON-GUID-EF513E68-4237-4CB3-98B3-2E203A68CBD4), then you don't need to restart the application server when DBs are being updated one at a time. But when one of the DBs is being restarted, we need to make sure that all the DB traffic goes to the other one. And vice versa.
Now, coming to whether the DB changes will get reflected in the application server, they will. But the schemas and all must suit. Also, you may have to fetch the cache from DB again (if you have some scheduled (or manual) cache fetching mechanism, it might be fine).